# mouse clicks to touch in android through unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

I made my first game in unity. 
initially i made it with keyboard controllers,
then added mouse click controls

but only 1 click is taken on touch devices

So to add touch controls 
is there a way to convert those keyboard/mouse click controls into touch one directly

or can a joystick kind of controller work?

Here is my code::

```
Button Scrpit

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RightButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture bgTexture;
    public int iconWidth = 32;
    public bool rightButtonPressed;
    public Vector2 buttonOffset = new Vector2(10, 10);

    private GUIStyle testStyle = new GUIStyle();

    void start(){
    }

    void OnGUI(){

        if (GUI.RepeatButton (new Rect (buttonOffset.x, buttonOffset.y, bgTexture.width, bgTexture.height),bgTexture,testStyle)){
            rightButtonPressed = true;
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: I would recommend you to upgrade to Unity 4.6 or up (if you haven't) and use the new Unity 4.6 GUI. It has many such things pre-implemented, which don't require you to code anything extra and includes support for all platforms. The pain you are taking to make a simple button will be drastically reduced with Unity's new GUI.

Comment: Thanks will upgrade it and try

Comment: Hi i installed unity 5.0 but still the touch and click problem is there

Comment: Check out the event system in unity 4.6 and above. You can add a event trigger (Pointer down for example) to a UI element. This handles multi touch and all the other stuff for you. In unity 4.6 and above the OnGUI method is deprecated.